# VictoryPie Custom Colors

Tags: reactjs, colors, victory-charts

I'm using VictoryPie to show my data, however, I want to be able to choose which color represents which section. Mainly because this is a pie chart of colors. I have seen a couple questions on StackOverflow asking something similar, but none of them fixed my problem.

My data object looks like:

```
[
    {
        "color": "#0000fe",
        "x": "blue",
        "y": 1
    },
    {
        "color": "#fe00fe",
        "x": "fuchsia",
        "y": 2
    },
    {
        "color": "#fefe00",
        "x": "yellow",
        "y": 8
    },
    {
        "color": "#008000",
        "x": "green",
        "y": 20
    }
]
```

And my code to render it is:

```
<VictoryPie
   data={this.state.sets}
   style={{
     data: { fill: (d) => d.color } 
   }}
/>
```

My Pie currently looks entirely black, and I wanted to know if I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you're taking a color from the wrong place, try this:

```
<VictoryPie
   data={this.state.sets}
   style={{
     data: { fill: (d) => d.datum.color } 
   }}
/>
```